# Possibilities of ERC721 image generation

Tags: dapps, erc-721, frontend, games

What image generation techniques could you suggest for a DApp game that utilizes ERC721? I know that CrypoKitties has a unique DNA sequence and different pieces of the sequence correspond to the different pieces of an image. Are there any other possibilities? Specifically, I am interested in the generation of a basketball player image. I am thinking if there is a way to implement this using a generative neural network or something more advanced so that the images will look could and the game will be as less centralized as possible.

Comment: This can give you an idea but I think you are looking for a more 'real' image https://github.com/stewartlord/identicon.js

If you find a suitable image generator you can give the token contract address and id as a seed

Comment: I think the topic is interesting but it falls outside of an Ethereum related QA site like this one. Try this if you want to randomly generate realistic faces for example https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/.